# Import data from Careers wiped out my Developer Story - I didn't expect that

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

I spent a bunch of time writing up my Developer Story.  I saw the link on the right rail prompting my to "import from your Careers profile".  My Careers profile was minimalist.  My Developer Story has been wiped out and is basically empty now (because my Careers profile was basically empty).

I would have expected it to **merge** instead of **replace** my Developer Story.  I'm upset that I lost my work.  At least have an "Are You Sure" prompt before wiping out my Developer Story to replace it with what was in my Careers profile.

Comment: Same here. After the first import, there is a warning that re-importing will reset your current profile, but that warning could be useful *before* the first import as well.

Comment: Doesn't it keep a version history like posts? oO

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Agreed. There is a warning there, but it's too easy to miss it and click the link before realizing it.

[image: Screenshot of the import functionality sidebar element, including the sentence "This will remove any existing data in your Story."]

We have added an extra prompt after clicking the link to prevent this from happening.

> This will erase your existing Developer Story and recreate it based on your Careers CV. Continue?

One side note: The manually triggered import is something that only exists during the private beta.

Comment: Ouch, that hurts to read. Contrast score of 2.48:1. Bad. :(

Comment: Even with an extra prompt, this does not look very clear. More clear wording such as "Your current Developer Story will be entirely removed" might be more useful. Remember that just because you put some words in front of a user, it doesn't mean they will read them, and understand what you meant.

Comment: If this is completed, why don't you mark the question as [status-completed]?  It will make it clear that this feature has been implemented. But if you're implementing more, like Richard said, you can mark it afterwards.

Comment: Why isn't this [meta-tag:feature-request] so it can be [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @cat It is now :)

Comment: @balpha [meta-tag:status-completed-completed]